Get mouse position when dragging a Draggable Container over a DragTarget?
I have a Container with a Draggable widget. And another Container() as DragTarget.
Dragging and dropping in this area is working very well.
But where I drop it is also important. If I drop on the first half of this DragTarget I want to do something and if a drop in the other half, I want to do something else.
Ok, I can use two dragAreas but is not applicable to me now because I guess that it might overload the system because this is just a one example. In the final project maybe we will multiple it for 40 or more.
How we can know the mouse´s position when it is over this DragTarget?
Well, using MouseRegion is not an option because only works if it is not pressed.
Using Listener solve it but remember, the click will happen on another container, the Draggable Container() so outside of the DragTarget Container(), the Listener inside it will not be triggered.
Is there another Widget that can help me with this or is the only solution divider this drop area in smaller areas?
Thank you!
Here I have a simple setup. The idea could be change for instance, the texts to a yellow color when dragging over the half area of thye blue box.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class dragDrop extends StatefulWidget {
  const dragDrop({super.key});

  @override
  State<dragDrop> createState() => _dragDropState();
}

class _dragDropState extends State<dragDrop> {
  Color dropColor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Draggable<int>(
            data: 0,
            feedback: panel(),
            child: panel(),
            onDragCompleted: () {
              print('completed');
            },
            onDragStarted: () {
              print('dragguing');
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 500,
          child: DragTarget<int>( builder:
              (BuildContext context,  List<dynamic> accepted, List<dynamic> rejected,) {
            return Container(
              color: dropColor,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    return Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          left: constraints.maxWidth / 2 - 40,
                          child: const Text(
                            'Upper side',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        ),

                        Positioned(
                          top: constraints.maxHeight - 20,
                          left: constraints.maxWidth / 2 - 40,
                          child: const Text(
                            'Down side',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        //const Text('Down side'),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            );

          },

           onWillAcceptWithDetails: (DragTargetDetails<int> details) {
             print('onWillAcceptWithDetails');
             dropColor = Colors.blueAccent;
             return true;
           },
          onAcceptWithDetails: (DragTargetDetails<int> details) {
             print('dropped');
             setState(() {
               dropColor = Colors.blue;
             });
          },
            onLeave: (data) {
              print('onLeave');
              setState(() {
                dropColor = Colors.blue;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget panel(){
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    );
  }
}


The Offset in DragTargetDetails doesn't give you a position of the mouse?

Also "40 or more" is no big deal.  What do you think a multi-month calendar widget has? :)

Randal, I guess that yes, onMove only will call when we enter dragging something over the DragTarget. So almost perfect but, it doesnt return a local position.
I tried to use referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.offset); to convert but it is not a global but it has as reference the start point where it was pressed. (I renew my asnwer) :)

@AlexandreB. globalToLocal works ok see this - this is a place where the dropped item position is added to the model

I guess that the difference is because I need to know a local position inside the DragTarget and you are inside the Draggable. So you have access to DragUpdateDetails and I have on onMove(DragTargetDetails). When I use RenderBox like your sample inside onMove I have a local value nor from zero. But you are using a TransformationController after get a local value. I will study more about it.

TransformationController is used since i am dropping into InteractiveViewer and it doesnt matter if you use DragTarget.onMove or Draggable.onDragUpdate - drag details are the same in both solutions

Well, looking inside the drag_taget.dart file we can find that _lastOffset is the return value in details.offset.
_lastOffset = globalPosition - dragStartPoint;

And here is the problem. When we are dragging a panel over a dragTarget and we watch details.offset in  onMove: (details){ is the _lastOffset value that we are receiving.
So imagine if we have one draggable in the left of the screen and a dragTarget in the right. When we click over and hold and drag this container until it hover the dreagTarget to fire the onMove event, we are receiving all this space between where we clicked less where we hover the target.
If we just do it: _lastOffset = globalPosition; everything works fine but change the original code doesn't seen a good idea.
In data of the draggable we can set the dragStartPoint in details.data.startDragPoint and then subtract it from the details.offset for instance.
-->Pskink, you are a master here, so your opinion is important, what do you think?
Thank you!

"In data of the draggable we can set the dragStartPoint in details.data.startDragPoint and then subtract it from the details.offset for instance." - this is a good solution, but honestly DragTargetDetails should have this additional Offset imho, i dont know why they did not add it

You are totally right!  And is so simple to implement direct in the source code. But the problem is when update the Flutter. Will lose everything.
